# General help: Building docker container with node.js

Tags: node.js, api, docker

**Motivation:**

I have an online API, and for every request I need to make a new docker container and execute the code I receive in the request and then delete the docker container. I have thought about using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/phusion/baseimage/) image as the standard image for docker in order to keep it lightweight.

**Questions:**

- Is it a good method? Since I am worried about the memory usage this method may take. However, I plan to run at most 5 containers at a time and queue all the other requests.
- Second, what other ways are there to securely make an online compiling API. I researched on the web and found this docker method very interesting since it removes any chance of abusing to the server with a malicious code that a person can write!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Is it a good method? Since I am worried about the memory usage this method may take. However, I plan to run at most 5 containers at a time
>     and queue all the other requests.

Yes this is good method and you can put limit for resource utilisation for docker containers.

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#--memory-swap-details

> - Second, what other ways are there to securely make an online compiling API. I researched on the web and found this docker method
>     very interesting since it removes any chance of abusing to the server
>     with a malicious code that a person can write!

I would suggest you to go with virtualisation, otherwise there will be always be a security risk. And docker is best choice for that. Other option is Vagrant, but it will be heavy on resources.